# SocialEngine – how remove additional signup steps?

Tags: php, socialengine

The administration area has options for customizing the signup process. The KB article is [here](http://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1642532-admin-panel---settings->-signup-process).

The problem is it doesn't offer the ability to remove unnecessary signup steps. I would like the signup process to be one single step – enter name, email and password. No further steps. This would mean no profile or photo steps.

Which part of the source code should I modify to remove these steps? I have tried hiding the forms, and also redirecting to home in the signup controller:

```
header('Location: /');
exit();
```

... but the issue then is that the account isn't created until after the profile step is complete so I don't think this is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1642532-admin-panel---settings-&gt%3B-signup-process

You can set "User Photo Upload (Do you want your users to be able to upload a photo of themselves upon signup?)" and "Require User Photo (Do you want to require your users to upload a photo of themselves upon signup?)" to NO :) -_-

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but this is only to disable the photo upload step. I would like to disable all other steps, leaving only the first step (email, password, name).

Comment: You can disable other steps from admin panel settings also. Setting all to "NO" will do the thing as far as i can remember. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check settings->signup process. Here you will find all the steps in signup and you can disable that. In database , table engine4_user_signup have the list of all the signup process. You can also disable from here.

Hopefully It will work for you.

Comment: If you want in single steps. There is one plugin quick signup. http://www.socialengine.com/customize/se4/mod-page?mod_id=1386.You can modify your requirment.

Comment: Thanks but under settings->signup process there is no option to disable the profile step. I want to have just one step: enter the email, password, name and no further steps.